GCC diagnostics and stdin
I am piping code through stdin to gcc like this: gcc -xc -o output - <<< ...
However, the format of diagnostics is different than when compiling a file. Specifically, what is missing is the caret (^) pointing to the place where the error is, as well as the whole line. There is a line number and position of the error, but I'd like the whole line printed, with the caret.
Is there an option that would make the format of diagnostics identical to when compiling a file (except, of course, using <stdin> in place of filename)?
I would like to avoid using a temporary file, if possible.

AFAICT this is a GCC limitation; clang properly displays the line and caret as expected. It might not be possible to do this without a temporary file.

@Lundin It's stdin from the gcc's point of view.

@Lundin, no. I am piping into gcc's stdin from stdout of some other program that generates C code. I'm not piping the stdout from gcc to a file. I want the stdout of gcc to remain in the terminal, and I would like to see errors in the same way as if I were compiling a file, not code from stdin.

This is probably just a limitation in the design of GCC. It may need the input to be seekable in order to print the line with the diagnostic, and pipes aren't seekable.

@Kresimir Ah gotcha. I'll delete the comments not to clutter down the question needlessly.

not 100% sure of what you're after, but my guess is something along the following behaviour is what you are asking/requiring/looking-for
cat /tmp/kresimir.c 
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello Kresimir\n")
}

# pip the contents int gcc 
$ cat /tmp/kresimir.c | gcc -xc -o /tmp/kresimir - 
<stdin>:4:28: error: expected ';' after expression
        printf("hello Kresimir\n")
                                  ^
                                  ;
1 error generated.

#
# and if using the 'normal' approach
# 
$ gcc -xc -o /tmp/kresimir /tmp/kresimir.c 
/tmp/kresimir.c:4:28: error: expected ';' after expression
        printf("hello Kresimir\n")
                                  ^
                                  ;
1 error generated.


As noted, initial version (run on an old macpro) gcc was aliased to:
"""gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
"""
another attempt, run on linux mint 20.2
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


cat kresimir.c 
#include <stdio.h>

double doNothing( double stuff ){ return stuff  }

int main()
{
    printf("hello Kresimiri %f\n", doNothing( 42.0 ) )

    doNothin( 45.0 );
}

$ cat kresimir.c | gcc -xc -o kresimir -
<stdin>: In function ‘doNothing’:
<stdin>:3:47: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
<stdin>: In function ‘main’:
<stdin>:7:55: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘doNothin’


is this what you are after ?

That looks like Clang's output, not GCC (gcc is aliased to clang on some platforms).

Yes, that's exactly what I want, except that is not what gcc does (at least not by default, I'm hoping there is some option that prints diagnostics and errors like your first example). So as an answer, this is useless, but as an illustration of the problem it is spot on.

In the second example, where actual GCC is used, you can see that the error messages are not complete: the line with the error is not printed at all, and there is no caret.

as @Barmer noted ... pipes are non seekable. 'line number and offset' are reasonable 'compromises' , its not a perfect world. You can always raise this with folks at gnu asking for this feature to be added. or use clang for compilation ....

@ticktalk are you sure this feature does not already exist? Are you sure it is impossible to get the similar output as in clang?

@kresimir , well i've not found it if it does, have you ? .

@ticktalk, no, but that's the whole point of asking here. Maybe someone knows.

TL;DR: Using the temp .c is the simplest.
After [much] experimentation:

If gcc sees - as the file arg, it assumes a pipe and will not output any input file text. AFAICT, it literally does a string compare for -.
Otherwise, gcc assumes the arg is a file and will try to open it a second time.
This is true even if the arg is a named pipe.

We can get the effect of the pipe by using the named pipe. On error, gcc will try to seek/reread the input.
But, after this extreme trickery, we still need a named pipe file.
Below are some files to save:

ccpipe
ccfile
bad.c
gud.c

Output of tests is below.

#!/bin/bash -
# ccpipe -- sample invocation of gcc in pipe

file_c=$1
echo "file_c='$file_c'"

# this should either be empty or "true" to suppress the second cat
nop_cmd=$2

mytemp="mytemp"
rm -fr $mytemp
mkdir -p $mytemp

pipe_file="$mytemp/mypipe"
mknod $pipe_file p

rm -f exe

function sender()
{

    ###sleep 1
    cat $file_c > $pipe_file

    ###sleep 1
    # NOTE: this second cat is _necessary_ for the error case
    # to test this, set nop_cmd to "true"
    # without the cat, gcc will just do "pipe mode"
    if [ -e $pipe_file ]; then
        $nop_cmd cat $file_c > $pipe_file
    fi

    exit 0
}

sender &
sender_pid=$!

###gcc -save-temps -xc -o exe $pipe_file
gcc -xc -o exe $pipe_file

###wait
rm -fr $mytemp


#!/bin/bash -
# ccfile -- sample invocation of gcc from file

file_c=$1

tmp_c=broken_compile.c
echo "tmp_c='$tmp_c'"

rm -f exe

cat $file_c > $tmp_c

gcc -xc -o exe $tmp_c
code=$?

if [ $code == 0 ]; then
    rm -f $tmp_c
fi

exit $code


// bad.c -- missing semicolon in main
//#include <stdio.h>

void borker(void);

int
main()
{
    borker()
}


// gud.c -- no errors
//#include <stdio.h>

void borker(void);

int
main()
{
    borker();
    return 0;
}

void borker(void) { }


Here is the output for various combinations of commands and options:

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CMD: ccfile bad.c
tmp_c='broken_compile.c'
broken_compile.c: In function ‘main’:
broken_compile.c:9:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
  borker()
          ^
          ;
 }
 ~
CODE: 1

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CMD: ccfile gud.c
tmp_c='broken_compile.c'
CODE: 0

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CMD: ccpipe bad.c
file_c='bad.c'
mytemp/mypipe: In function ‘main’:
mytemp/mypipe:9:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
  borker()
          ^
          ;
 }
 ~
CODE: 0

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CMD: ccpipe gud.c
file_c='gud.c'
CODE: 0

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CMD: ccpipe bad.c true
file_c='bad.c'
mytemp/mypipe: In function ‘main’:
mytemp/mypipe:9:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
CODE: 0

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CMD: ccpipe gud.c true
file_c='gud.c'
CODE: 0


UPDATE:

While this is enlightening, it is not a practical solution, because creating a named pipe is pretty much the same as creating a temporary .c file. The whole point of this question is to find a way around that. –
Kresimir

I included the ccpipe version to show that the workaround was more cumbersome than the simpler ccfile version.
I guess my TL;DR wasn't enough of a hint. Let me be more clear: There is no way to get gcc to do what you want [without insanity ;-)].
If you want this feature, file a feature request [bug]. But, even if you do get it, it won't be available in 99.44% of existing gcc versions, so it will have limited use for the next decade or so.
And, why do you want this?
Warning: These may seem a bit harsh:

You think it should exist because clang does it?
It's a "neat" thing to do?
I don't want to "clutter up" my file system with zillions of temp files? (Note that this can be [easily] managed.)
I wrote the generator program and it outputs to stdout and I don't want to change it [to save the generated text to a file] because I have a vision of how it should work.

What is the XY problem?
Furthermore, you really don't want to do this:
Even printing the extra source line usually isn't enough for serious debugging. In many cases, it is necessary to examine the entire file to determine the true cause of an error. For example:
// ngud.c -- error
//#include <stdio.h>

#if NEED_BORKER
void borker(void);
#endif

int
main()
{
    borker();
    return 0;
}

#if NEED_BORKER
void borker(void) { }
#endif

Here is the [full] diagnostic:
file_c='ngud.c'
mytemp/mypipe: In function ‘main’:
mytemp/mypipe:11:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘borker’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  borker();
  ^~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

Even with the exact text of the line where the error occurred (more correctly, was detected), this doesn't show the true reason for the error.
We need the whole file to determine that NEED_BORKER wasn't defined vs. the prototype was in a .h that we forgot the #include for.
In the ccfile version, note that if compilation is clean, the temp file was deleted. On an error, the file was kept so that it could be examined as described.
So, you asking for a feature/workaround that really isn't all that useful to begin with. Even if you were only using clang, I wouldn't use it for the above reason. (And, I've done plenty of such dynamic code generation / metaprogramming).
However, there is a way ...
But ... Be careful what you wish for, you may actually get it ...
We would use an invoker program and a shared library. We'll use the LD_PRELOAD feature and interceptor functions, similar to what valgrind does:

Create a shared library. Call it (e.g.) libfake_out_cc.so

Create an invoker script (or program), similar to ccpipe. It will substitute (e.g.) % for the input filename (-).

The script will invoke cc with (e.g.) env LD_PRELOAD=libfake_out_cc.so cc -Werror -xc -o exe %

The shared library will have interceptors for [any variants of] open, close, read, stat, etc.

Ordinarily, these interceptors will just pass through to the "real" functions in glibc

But, if the open interceptor sees the filename % (e.g. open("%",...)), on the first such call, it reads in data from stdin and saves it [*]

On any such open call, the interceptor will then open a dummy file instead (e.g. /dev/null) and return the valid file descriptor. Let's call it fdfake

On any syscalls that use file descriptor fdfake, the library will intercept such calls.

It will feed the stdin captured data to to the read(fdfake,...) syscalls.

When it sees close(fdfake), it closes the file descriptor and resets.


For an example of such a LD_PRELOAD based interceptor program, see my answer: How can I intercept a function from glibc and print the values of its parameters? There are many other examples.
[*] Saved? In a dynamic malloc array? But, what if the data is large? Do we fall back to a hidden file? ;-)

nice. can you supply the output of gcc --version and your platform. NB: the op also specified 'I would like to avoid using a temporary file, if possible.'

While this is enlightening, it is not a practical solution, because creating a named pipe is pretty much the same as creating a temporary .c file. The whole point of this question is to find a way around that.

@Kresimir I've updated my answer ...

@Craig Estey Thanks, it's a really nice answer, and I'm sure it took a lot of effort, but unfortunately, it's not an answer to my question. It makes a lot of assumptions that are not really applicable here (but might be useful for anyone else coming upon this topic). I was merely asking if anyone is aware of some option that can be passed to gcc to have it output full diagnostics in case of code being piped through stdin, like clang. While fancy workarounds are interesting to consider, they are not really applicable to this concrete practical issue.

Regarding:

There is no way to get gcc to do what you want [without insanity ;-)].

I'd like some definitive proof of that claim. Just because we don't know how to do it, it is not instantly clear that it is impossible.
